# Rotate map in mapbox in directon I move

Tags: android, mapbox

I have a program in Android, that uses Mapbox map. I have a problem with rotating the map at the direction I go, there is a camera mode with a arrow that shows North, but I want moving directions to be to the north and the map to rotate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can set the camera mode to `CameraMode#TRACKING_COMPASS` which will automatically follow your position and rotate the map based on the gyroscope. You can also provide a custom `CompassEngine` with `LocationComponent#setCompassEngine` if you feel like the default one is too jerky, or the update rate doesn't fit your needs.